# CSS - Custom styling on radio button

Tags: css, forms, radio-button, checked

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/5qmnptuk/4/

I'm trying to craete a custom radio button.

Ive hidden the radio button and then created the new one with :after on the label.

I'm trying to use :checked to style the clicked but its not working

Can anyone see why this doesn't work.

```
    .form-group{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    label{
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 25px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    label:after{
        bottom: -1px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        border-radius: 25px;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 25px;
        margin-right: 25px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -31px;
        width: 25px;
    }

    input[type=radio]{
        display: none;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked + label{
        content: \2022;
        color: red;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 18px; 
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

#### 1 - Your input needs to be *before* the `label`

The `+` and `~` CSS selectors only select siblings *after* an element in the DOM, so you need to have the input before the label.

#### 2 - Your label isn't assigned to the input

To assign the label, use the `for` attribute, and give the input an ID:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" id="custom" />
    <label for="custom">Label</label>
  </div>
```

#### 3 - The content for the pseudo element is missing quotes.

#### 4 - You aren't applying the styles to the after element of the label, you were applying them to the label directly:

```
 input[type=radio]:checked + label{
    content: \2022;
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px; 
}
```

Selects the label, while:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after{
    content: "\2022";
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px; 
}
```

Selects the `after` element

[Updated, working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ep6sf4xs/)

Comment: Great answer Jacob.

Comment: one more. all the `radio`'s must have equal attribute `name` in order to allow user to change the selection.

Comment: @spirit Good point, but that isn't really relative to the question, so I didn't add it to the answer :)

Comment: @JacobGray, maybe it isn't really relative, but this issue is likely to be his next problem =)

Answer (score 0):

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qmnptuk/5/) where I've added id for the radio and label needs

```
for="radioId"
```

to be able to work like that

also the label needs to be after the radio button